# Run an IRC-Bot on a server?

Tags: java, irc

Is it possible to run a JAVA application (an IRC-Bot) on a server?

I developed it with java and it works fine, login works, sending messages works and so on, the bot is full functional.

I'd now like to run the bot on a server so I don't have to run it locally and be online with my computer 24/7.

If it isn't possible to run a normal JAVA application on a server, what other possibilities do I have?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to run a Java application on a server.

Depending on how you wrote your application, you'll need:

- A tomcat enabled hosting; or
- A dedicated virtual machine in which you can configure firewall ports, running apps, etc.

Would need more information to answer your question better.

Comment: Thanks, good to hear! Further information will be added this afternoon, if possible.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can install Java applications on a server - just as any other piece of software. Running on a server *usually* (i.e. not always) just requires, that the application does not use any kind of GUI and that some additional start/stop scripts must be written and put into the right place.

But the gory details vary between the server's operating system, distribution, the frameworks your have used,... Therefore this *very* generic question will not help you with the details.

Comment: Thanks, for now that's all the information I have.. I'm going to check out the details this afternoon, if possible. I'll give further information then.